# .htaccess redirect to map old site structure to new site structure

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have revamp my website with new CMS.

**Old site structure:** 
www.domain.com/arc/web/index.shtml
www.domain.com/arc/web/category/page.shtml

**New site structure:**
www.domain.com
www.domain.com/category/page

**I need to map the webpages of my old site structure to the new site structure:**
www.domain.com/arc/web/index.shtml to www.domain.com
www.domain.com/arc/web/category/page.shtml to www.domain.com/category/page

I have tried the following redirect but not working properly:

> Redirect 301 /arc/web/aboutwecaneip/
>   http://www.wecaneip.com/about-us/what-we-do
>   Redirect 301 /arc/web/aboutwecaneip/GuidingPrinciples.shtml
>   http://www.wecaneip.com/about-us/what-we-do

What is the best way to handle this?

Thanks in advance for all the help and advise.

Answer (score 0):

This is a good use for mod-rewrite.

Here's a configuration for your specific use case that you'll want to put in your apache configuration:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/arc/web/index.shtml$ /index.html [L]
   RewriteRule ^/arc/web/(.*)/(.*).shtml$ /$1/$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```